# How to calculate $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i}{i+1}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation

I have been working with some probabilities and I am not sure if I'm correct but one of my probabilities is reduced to this formula, however, I don't recall a method to solve it:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i}{i+1}$$

I can't seem to decompose this... What's the approach I should take?

Comment: hint: $\frac{i}{i+1}=\frac{i+1}{i+1}-\frac{1}{i+1}=1-\frac{1}{i+1}$

Comment: Can I use the formula for the sum of r**x with -1 as x and i+1 as r? I am unsure

Comment: You cannot use that, because that only works when $r$ is a constant. Here the $i$ is different for each term.

Comment: What approach should I take then? I am not taking any courses related to this so my assumption is that the formula I found could be found differently... however, I would still like to verify this first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since
$$\frac{i}{i+1}=1-\frac{1}{i+1}$$
we have
$$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{i+1}=1-\frac1n\Bigl(\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{n+1}\Bigr)\ .$$
The sum in brackets on the right hand side is unlikely to have any simple exact evaluation.  However it is given approximately, if $n$ is large, by
$$\ln n-1+\gamma\ ,$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html).  So
$$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{i+1}\approx1-\frac{\ln n-1+\gamma}{n}\ .$$